# Mac Mail with Exchange stopped working, LibSasl2SASLClient error

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange

I've had Mail.app on Lion (and previously Snow Leopard) successfully working with my company's Exchange 2007 for the last couple of years, but today it seems like it's decided not to work. Instead, I get an error message in the UI that it was unable to connect, and in Console.app, the only related message I get seems to be:

```
25/06/2012 12:32:01.490 Mail: [<_LibSasl2SASLClient: 0x7fcb2944de10> mechanism:
PLAIN security layer: no] Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure:
```

And that's all. The connection does work with Outlook, however. A Google search hasn't turned up anything useful. Any thoughts on where I can go with this? Unfortunately our IT team doesn't support Mail.app (only Outlook) and they're even reluctant to support Lion, so they won't be much help, and I'd really rather use Mail.app than that horrible bloatware.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the account and adding it back?  This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Yeah, done that twice. My iCal isn't working either. It all works on my iPhone though. So puzzling.

Comment: I've run into the same bit of confusion before when my iPhone was able to connect and my MB was not. The iPhone connection uses ActiveSync and Mail.app uses Exchange Web Services.  Unless the problem on your IT end affected both, you wouldn't have noticed it on your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was some kind of configuration problem on the Exchange server. It was resolved by my IT team. Unfortunately I don't have any more details than that.